# How to pass type argument to method

Tags: scala

I defined a type something like this:

```
type Similarity = (String, Int) => Boolean
```

Now I created a function that expects this type as an argument to method like this:

```
def calculate(param: Similarity) = {
    println("hi")
  }
```

My question is how can I pass arguments to calculate function? for instance if I want to pass a string and a number?

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, write:

```
calculate((s: String, n: Int) => s.length > n)
```

Comment: I think I forgot to ask some details so can you ask my other question where I have detailed out everything for your consideration? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481850/how-to-invoke-a-method-that-expects-a-type-function-with-arguments

Answer (score 0):

the `calculate` function takes an function as an argument. so you can pass a anonymous function like this.

```
scala> type Similarity = (String, Int) => Boolean
defined type alias Similarity

scala> def calculate(param: Similarity) = { println("hi") }
calculate: (param: Similarity)Unit

scala> calculate((x: String, y: Int) => x.toInt == y )
hi
```

Comment: I think I forgot to ask some details so can you ask my other question where I have detailed out everything for your consideration? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481850/how-to-invoke-a-method-that-expects-a-type-function-with-arguments

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a function whose return type is the type you created as

```
   def func(x: String, y: Int): Similarity = {
      if(x.equalsIgnoreCase("Joe")) (x, y) => true
      else (x, y) => false
    }
```

Then if you have a data as

```
val data = Seq(("Joe", 1))
```

You can call calculate as

```
data.map(x => calculate(func(x._1, x._2)))
```

Comment: I think I forgot to ask some details so can you ask my other question where I have detailed out everything for your consideration? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481850/how-to-invoke-a-method-that-expects-a-type-function-with-arguments

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how can I pass arguments to calculate function? for instance if I want to pass a string and a number?

The argument of `calculate` is a `Similarity`, *not* a string and a number.  You can pass a string and a number to `param` inside `calculate`, e.g.

```
def calculate(param: Similarity) = param("a", 0) || param("b", 1)
```

or to add parameters to `calculate` such as

```
def calculate(param: Similarity, x: String, y: Int) = param(x, y + 1)
```

Comment: I think I forgot to ask some details so can you ask my other question where I have detailed out everything for your consideration? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481850/how-to-invoke-a-method-that-expects-a-type-function-with-arguments