# How to invoke a method that expects a Type function with arguments

Tags: scala

This is my code and I get following error when I try to invoke my m1 method:

```
trait Function4[-T1, -T2, -T3, -T4, +R] extends Function {
  def apply(arg1: T1, arg2: T2, arg3: T3, arg4: T4): R
}

class Function(args: String*) extends Object {

}

class A extends Object {

  type CallbackFunction = Function4[Object, Object, Object, Object, Promise[String]]

  def m1(callback: CallbackFunction): Unit = {

  }

  def m2 = {
    m1(
      (a:Object, b:Object, c:Object, d: Object) => {
        println("good here!")
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Error is :
Type mismatch, expected: A.this.CallbackFunction, actual: (Object, Object, Object, Object) => Promise[String]

Comment: The return type of your `CallbackFunction` is `Promise[String]`, not `Unit`.

Comment: Thank you for rectifying this, I corrected it in example

Comment: You shouldn't correct the error message, you should correct the code ;) Your function returns `Unit` but it should return `Promise[String]`. So create one instead of only printing text.

Comment: Can you give an example how would I do that?

Comment: You can take inspiration from the `Promise` API. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Promise$.html assuming your library uses the standard `scala.concurrent.Promise`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your original code (revision 1) works fine in Scala 2.12, not work in Scala 2.11.

If you want you code work in Scala 2.11 you can rewrite code like this:

```
class A extends Object {

  type CallbackFunction[A] = Function4[Object, Object, Object, Object, A]

  def m1[A](callback: CallbackFunction[A]): Unit = {

  }

  def m2 = {
    m1(
      (a:Object, b:Object, c:Object, d: Object) => {
        println("good here!")
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Or change `Function4[Object, Object, Object, Object, _]` to `Function4[Object, Object, Object, Object, Unit]`.

If you want you current code (revision 2) work, you only need to change `Promise[String]` to `Unit`.

Comment: I can not change anything in my CallbackFunction, this is a library code. I'm not sure how to use that

Comment: I need Promise[String] and can not use Unit because this is not my code. Any help how would I use it? I'm also using Scala version 2.12.1

Comment: @Taimur Assuming Promise is the `scala.concurrent.Promise`, you could do something like this:
    def m2 = {
      m1(
        (a:Object, b:Object, c:Object, d: Object) => {
          println("good here!")
          Promise.successful("any string you want")
          // or if something wrong happended, you can return this
          // Promise.failed(new RuntimeException("something wrong happened"))
        }
      )
    }

If you want return something else, you can browse the `Promise` API.

Answer (score 0):

Why is your code defining your own `Function` (which doesn't describe a function) and your own `Function4` (when there is one in the standard library)?

If, as your comment to another answer says, "I can not change anything in my CallbackFunction, this is a library code", this very much looks like a library nobody should be using.

However, the direct answer to your question is that the argument you pass to `m1` must be a function returning `Promise[String]`. Assuming `Promise` is the standard `scala.concurrent.Promise` instead of another type defined by the library, one possibility would be

```
  (a:Object, b:Object, c:Object, d: Object) => Promise()
```

But that would only make it compile (so would passing `null`!); it isn't at all clear what you want to *do*.